# Same In-App product shared among multiple apps (Android)

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

Is it possible to have the same in-app product(managed) in multiple apps? Such that if a user buys a premium upgrade in one of the apps, he gets premium upgrade in all of them.

Note that I'm not planning to maintain a user database currently and trying to find a solution using Google's in-app billing API alone if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, unless you build your own database. Entitlements are always related to an app (package name), which means if a user buys a SKU of App A, the Play Billing library can only pull entitlements for App A from its code.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Thanks.
I went a complete different route and put everything in one modular app. Much easier to work with any way.

Comment: @SirBarksalot Do you have any guide for that? Or code example?